# Pycharm install fail with "Invalid Log Path"

Tags: macos, installation, pycharm

I downloaded a Pycharm community mac OSX version. But after installation, each time I try to open it. It gives me this error. I can't find any information about this error after I google the error.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I downloaded a professional version, but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

OK. It turn out be a permission problem. Just chmod 777 the directory(mkdir before). Then this problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Start --> Search "idea.log". In this file change the path.